# How to make video thumbnails like Facebook [CSS]

Tags: css

I am looking to make video thumbnails like on facebook but I am not able to get that play button over the thumbnail like on facebook.

[image]

**CODE**

**HTML**

```
<a href="watch-video.php?c=1244">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/X0OdLlX-cIw/1.jpg">
    <b></b>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.wall_video a {display: block; width: 128px; height: 96px; padding: 4px; border: 1px solid #cccccc; position: relative}
.wall_video a img {display: block; width: 128px; height: 96px; }
.wall_video a b {background: url(images/play-icon.png) no-repeat; display: block; width: 28px; height: 30px; position: absolute;}
```

When I try to float the `img` then the button goes right on top. At first I thought its position:relative and negative top margin but when I checked the source of facebook they dont use relative positioning.

Comment: Side note: you'd be better off using a more semantic element, or rather, since there isn't one then an element *without* semantic meaning like `<span>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.wall_video a b {
    /* ... */
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
}
```